# How to check if document set exists before importing

Tags: 2010, document-set

I have the following document set extension method, I need that it doesnt try to copy if the document set already exist but dont know how.

```
 public static DocumentSet CopyTo(this DocumentSet documentSet, SPFolder targetFolder, SPContentTypeId targetContentTypeId)
        {
            Logger.LogDebug("DocumentSetExtensions", "CopyTo(this DocumentSet documentSet, SPFolder targetFolder, SPContentTypeId targetContentTypeId)", "BEGIN"); 
            if (targetFolder == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("SPFolder targetFolder");
            if (targetContentTypeId == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("SPContentTypeId targetContentTypeId");
            DocumentSet newDocumentSet = null;
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // Export the document set to memory
                    documentSet.Export(ms);

                    // Store the current metadata
                    Hashtable properties = documentSet.Item.Properties;

                    // Import the document set from memory into the target library
                    newDocumentSet = DocumentSet.Import(ms, documentSet.Folder.Name, targetFolder, targetContentTypeId, properties, documentSet.ParentList.ParentWeb.CurrentUser);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError("DocumentSetExtensions", "CopyTo(this DocumentSet documentSet, SPFolder targetFolder, SPContentTypeId targetContentTypeId)", ex);
                throw;
            }
            Logger.LogDebug("DocumentSetExtensions", "CopyTo(this DocumentSet documentSet, SPFolder targetFolder, SPContentTypeId targetContentTypeId)", "END");
            return newDocumentSet;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

piece of cake at the end.

```
if(!targetFoolder.Exists
```